# How do you send django objects to javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I want to send a django object over to my javascript code when a button is clicked.
The following code is present in my `views.py` file:

```
def index(request):
    venues = Venue.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'venues':venues})
```

The following code is present in my `index.html` file:

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{% block content %}
<script>
    var count = 0;
    function changePlayers(test_venue) {
        count++;
        document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = "Players: "+(count+{{venue.players}})+"/{{venue.total_players}}";
    }
</script>
<h1>Venues</h1>
{% for venue in venues %}
<div class="card">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <p class="card-text" id="player" style="margin-left: 20px">Players: {{venue.players}}/{{venue.total_players}}</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-bottom:20px" onclick="changePlayers({{venue}})">Book Now</button>
     </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

There is an error in the 4th line of the javascript code that says `Property assignment expected.javascript`. My main question is how do I pass the 'venue' object to the javascript code and use it, when I click the submit button? Is the way in which I went about it even possible? What would be the correct way of going about it?

I'm sorry if this question is silly, I have just started learning django.

Comment: May you share the rendered javascript?

Comment: This is all the javacript that I've used. The code in the `base.html` file is just boiler plate bootstrap stuff. When I run the server the page is displayed but nothing happens when I click the button (I want the count of the players to increase by 1). I don't know if that's because of some error in my implementation or whether I'm not doing this in the correct way.

Comment: It'd be useful to show how the javascript is rendered as the error seems to be coming from javascript itself. Maybe django is outputting incorrect JS?

Comment: @Akashkariappa why do you even **render** into javascript? A script writing another script is not a very sensible solution (Not to mention the potential XSS attacks). Why don't you simply get the value you need from the html itself in the javascript?